# Reset anydesk ID on cloned raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have cloned a raspberry and found that anydesk has the same ID. I tried to uninstall it with the command

```
sudo apt purge anydesk
```

and install it again but the ID remain the same. I don't understand how it is possible because I removed the file system.conf. There are other things to do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution: you have also to remove the folder:

```
sudo rm -r /home/pi/.anydesk
```